# Unable to change target .NET-framework from 2.0 to higher without breaking Android and iOS projects (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I'm trying to change the targeted .NET-framework from 2.0 to 4.61 for my Xamarin.Forms solution (consists of three projects). However as soon as I do this I'm getting errors stating that the project is no longer compatible with monoandroid90 and xamarinios10.

I've tried switching Target Framework for the Android-project to different versions, but the error message stays the same.

I've been searching how to fix this for a while now, but I'm at a loss and very new to cross-platform development. Does anyone have any insight as to have I could solve this?

Let me know if I can add some more info.

```
NU1201  Project IJAW_Dev is not compatible with monoandroid90 (MonoAndroid,Version=v9.0). Project IJAW_Dev supports: net461 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1)
Error   NU1201  Project IJAW_Dev is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win-x86. Project IJAW_Dev supports: net461 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1) 
Error   NU1201  Project IJAW_Dev is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0). Project IJAW_Dev supports: net461 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1)
Error   NU1201  Project IJAW_Dev is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win-x64. Project IJAW_Dev supports: net461 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1)
Error   NU1201  Project IJAW_Dev is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win. Project IJAW_Dev supports: net461 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1) 
Warning     The project 'IJAW_Dev' cannot be referenced. The referenced project is targeted to a different framework family (.NETFramework)
```

Comment: you need to target DLLs as **.net standard 2.0**

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, do you think "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library-guidance/cross-platform-targeting" would put me on the right track?

Comment: you figured it now out. remove net461 and you're fine

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by using

```
   <TargetFrameworks>net461;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

Comment: .NET Framework 4.6.1 does implement .NET Standard 2.0. So back to origin, why do you need `net461`?

Comment: I wanted to try using a plugin that needed .NET 4.6.1

Comment: Did this work as a permanent solution for you? I'm wondering because I'm having the same problem. I can't select anything higher than 2.0 from the app properties menu. Did you change it in the .csproj file?

Comment: really useful, thanks.
I had also to adjust some iOS configurations:
- linker behaviour to framework sdk only NOT link to all,
- tick only 
            - perform all...
            - strip native...
            - use current